# XSLT to Text file - Whitespace and Page breaks ignored

Tags: xslt, whitespace

I have created an XSLT from an rtf template to generate a text file.

However, white spaces and page breaks are being ignored on the text file, output text file is just data and no formatting.

My requirement is to create text file with data displayed in the same format and layout as the original rtf template holds.

Comment: Please share the inputs, XSLT and the desired output so as to get a proper solution.

Comment: Very likely you are running afoul of [whitespace stripping](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) in the stylesheet document, but there may be other issues as well.  Use `xsl:text` or possibly `xsl:value-of` to insert literal all-whitespace text into the output tree.  Present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem to get better help.

Comment: If you tell us what you are doing, then we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong can't you try using HTML tags put your data inside  and apply the needed formatting.

Also if possible would you mind sharing your xslt.